# 2 instances of the same embedded form with Symfony & Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm looking to display 2 instances of the same form inside another form with twig but I can't figure out how.

Here my first form:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // build form
    $builder
        ->add('contenu', 'text', array(
            'attr'                  =>  array('maxlength' => 255),
            'empty_data'            =>  "Question par défaut"
        ))
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'attr'                  =>  array('accept' => "image/png, image/jpeg")
        ))
        ->add('contenuQuestion', 'collection', array(
              'type'                =>  new QuizzReponseType(), // here the embedded form
              'allow_add'           =>  true,
              'allow_delete'        =>  true,
              'cascade_validation'  =>  true,
         ))
    ;
}
```

with in the entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="OC\QuizzBundle\Entity\QuizzReponse", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
private $contenuQuestion;

function __construct() {
    $this->contenuQuestion = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Here the embedded form:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // build form
    $builder
        ->add('contenu', 'text', array(
            'attr'                  =>  array('maxlength' => 50),
            'empty_data'            =>  "Réponse par défaut"
        ))
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'attr'                  =>  array('accept' => "image/png, image/jpeg")
        ))
    ;
}
```

The problem is in my view. I want to have 2 instances of the embedded form but the collection seems empty.

It's working well with only one embedded form (NB: my first form is also inside another form but it's not relevant for my question):

```
// embedded form content field
{{ form_widget(form.contenuQuizz.vars.prototype.contenuQuestion.vars.prototype.contenu) }}
```

And I'm looking to do something like that:

```
// embedded form1 content field
{{ form_widget(form.contenuQuizz.vars.prototype.contenuQuestion.0.vars.prototype.contenu) }}

// embedded form2 content field
{{ form_widget(form.contenuQuizz.vars.prototype.contenuQuestion.1.vars.prototype.contenu) }}
```

It looks like the problem is that the collection is not initialized but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to do that ? (with twig and not JavaScript if possible)

Thanks in advance,

Maugun

Comment: Are you adding two questions to your entity?  The collection type will display as many forms as you have items in the entity collection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you mean "do I have 2 questions load from the db by my entity" or "Do I initialize 2 question in my entity" ?
If the first one, no I don't have any question in my db, I'm trying to fill my db with thoses questions !
If the second one, I've tried but I have no success so far in trying to do this.

Comment: For new entities, just add two questions when you create it in your controller then pass to the form.  If your form type is properly constructed then your will get two question forms.  By the way, just use the default form rendering http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form to get started then go back and pretty it up.

Comment: Okay I get it know ! Thanks mate ! I will try that on Monday (I don't have access to the code before Monday) and I let you know if it works.

Comment: It works ! Thanks man !